# How does 'function' and 'use' and 'array_filter' work in PHP?

Tags: php, function, array-filter

I am familiar with creating a PHP function placed at the top of the .php file such as:

```
function my_little_function($parm1,$parm2) {
   if ($parms < $parm2) {
   return "yes";
   } else {
   return "no";
   }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
$result = my_little_function("1","2");
echo "The answer is $result." . "\n";
```

I have some code, I didn't write it, which uses "function" and "use" together inside of a traditional use of a function like my_little_function above.

I'm puzzled by this and have some questions for you more experienced PHP developers. Here is part of the working PHP code I'm referring to:

```
$neededObject = array_filter($st_ny_trip->STOPS->STOP,function($e) use ($final_desired_dest,$connect_raw){return $e->NAME == $final_desired_dest && DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y g:i:s a", $e->TIME) > $connect_raw;});
```

`$e` is not set in any part of the function or the rest of the program, so what is using `$e`? How does it get passed a value and how is it being used? There appears to be no name for this function, so I don't know how it is being called, how is that being done?

Is this creating a function, on-the-fly to be used and it gets re-generated each time this code gets called? If it's a function, why not create it outside of this function and call it?

I've also not used 'use' myself yet, so that's unfamiliar to me. I looked it up on php.net and it just looks like a way to assign a value to something, but I couldn't find any practical examples to demonstrate why it's needed and when it should be used.

I looked up `array_filter` and it says it's "Filters elements of an array using a callback function". I don't know what a call back function is. Is it referring to `function($e)`?

Should the above line of PHP code for `$neededObject` be formatted differently so it is easier to read?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: PHP is so awesome, it has a different argument order for `array_map()` and `array_filter()`. PHP will tell you if you're doing it wrong, but still. Weird.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to explain what's going on.

We want to duplicate the input of an array: so if the input is `aa`, the output would be `aaaa`.

So the normal way, would be to create a function and then pass it to [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$array = range('a', 'e');

$new_array = array_map('duplicate', $array);
print_r($new_array);

function duplicate($string){
    return $string.$string;
}
```

[**Online demo**](https://eval.in/42749)

But what if you want to use this function only once ? Since **PHP 5.3**, there is something called [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), we use it like the following:

```
$array = range('a', 'e');

$new_array = array_map(function($string){
    return $string.$string;
}, $array);
print_r($new_array);
```

[**Online demo**](https://eval.in/42748)

Now, let's say for example you want to add a standard value from another variable. That's easy with global variables. But as we know, global variables are evil and should be avoided. We may use `use()`:

```
$array = range('a', 'e');
$standard_value = ',';

$new_array = array_map(function($string)use($standard_value){
        // $standard_value becomes available inside the function
    return $string.$standard_value.$string;
}, $array);
print_r($new_array);
```

[**Online demo**](https://eval.in/42747)

`use()` can be become also useful if we use a reference to write to an external variable while looping:

```
$array = range('a', 'e');
$another_string = '';

$new_array = array_map(function($string)use(&$another_string){// note &
    $another_string .= $string.$string; // overwrite $another_string
    return $string.$string;
}, $array);
print_r($new_array);
echo PHP_EOL . $another_string;
```

[**Online demo**](https://eval.in/42746)

Answer (score 4):

the `$e` variable acts as a normal function parameter, and will thus be passed by the code calling the function, see the documentation for the value of `$e` when using `array_filter`.

The `use` statement imports variables from the local scope into the [anonymous' function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)'s scope.

```
$myvar = 'world';
$myFunc = function ($test) use ($myvar) {
    return $test . ' ' . $myvar;
};
echo $myFunc('hello'); // echoes 'hello world';
```

If you did not include the `use ($myvar)` part, then `isset($myvar)` would return false from **inside** the anonymous function, since it has a separate scope.